# Generic Lists and Findall predicate search child list

Tags: .net, generics, predicate, findall

From the code below I am able to use a predicate search and find all the merchants that have an Id greater than 4, using a similar approach how would I go about returning all the merchants and their vouchers where the Voucher had a VoucherTypeID of 3 lets say.

Thanks in Advance

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Merchant> merchants = new List<Merchant>(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
             List<Voucher> vcs = new List<Voucher>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            { 

                vcs.Add(new Voucher(j,"Voucher" + j.ToString(),i, j, "Type_" +j.ToString()));

            }
              merchants.Add(new Merchant(i, i.ToString() + "_Merchant",vcs));
        }

        //This will return all the merchant's where the ID is greater than 4

        Predicate<Merchant> filterByID;
        MerchantFilter filter = new MerchantFilter(4);
        filterByID = new Predicate<Merchant>(filter.FilterByMerchantGT4);
        List<Merchant> filteredMerchants = merchants.FindAll(filterByID);  

    }

    public class MerchantFilter 
    {
        private int idValue;
        public bool FilterByMerchantGT4(Merchant merch) 
        {

            return merch.MerchantID > idValue;
        }
        public MerchantFilter(int value)
        {
            idValue = value; 
        }
    } 

public class Merchant
{
    public int MerchantID { get; set; }
    public string MerchantName { get; set; }
    public List<Voucher> MerchantVouchers { get; set; }
    public Merchant(int id, string Name, List<Voucher> vouchers)
    {
        MerchantID = id;
        MerchantName = Name;
        MerchantVouchers = vouchers;

    }
}
public class Voucher
{
    public int VoucherID { get; set; }
    public string VoucherName { get; set; }
    public int MerchantVoucherID { get; set; }
    public int VoucherTypeID { get; set; }
    public string VoucherTypeName { get; set; }
    public Voucher(int ID, string Name, int merchantID, int typeID, string TypeName)
    {
        VoucherID = ID;
        VoucherName = Name;
        MerchantVoucherID = merchantID;
        VoucherTypeID = typeID;
        VoucherTypeName = TypeName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using linq, you could do this:

```
var query = from merchant in merchants
            let filteredVouchers = from voucher in merchant.MerchantVouchers
                                   where voucher.VoucherTypeID == 3
                                   select voucher
            select new { merchant, filteredVouchers };
```

or, equivalently, this:

```
var query =
    merchants.Select(
        merchant =>
        new
        {
            merchant,
            filteredVouchers = merchant.MerchantVouchers.Where(voucher => voucher.VoucherTypeID == 3)
        })
        .Select(t => new { t.merchant, t.filteredVouchers });
```

or, avoiding linq:

```
foreach(var merchant in merchants)
{
    var filteredVouchers = merchant.MerchantVouchers.FindAll(v => v.VoucherTypeID == 3);
    //...some useful code here
}
```

Notice how you don't need to define the MerchantFilter class.  You can use a lambda expression to define the argument to the FindAll method.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Solved my issues.